# kafkaUtils.createDirectStream gives an error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I changed a line from createStream to createDirectStream since the new library does not support createStream

I have checked it from here https://codewithgowtham.blogspot.com/2022/02/spark-streaming-kafka-cassandra-end-to.html

```
scala> val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "sparkgroup", topicpMap).map(_._2)
    <console>:44: error: overloaded method value createDirectStream with alternatives:
      [K, V](jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext, locationStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategy, consumerStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[K,V], perPartitionConfig: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.PerPartitionConfig)org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[K,V]] <and>
      [K, V](ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, locationStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategy, consumerStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[K,V], perPartitionConfig: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.PerPartitionConfig)org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[K,V]]
     cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, String, String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int])
           val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "sparkgroup", topicpMap).map(_._2)
```

Comment: are you just want to read from Kafka? What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I'm using spark 3.2.1

Comment: then you Structured Streaming, not legacy Streaming. Follow links in the answer

Comment: Linked article uses a super old version of Spark and Kafka. Please refer official documentation in the future

Answer (score 1):

It's already 2022nd - there should be a very specific reason for using legacy Spark Streaming.  Instead you need to use [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) that is much more easier to use than legacy one. With it, work with [Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) is very simple:

```scala
// create stream
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
// Decode payload - it heavily depends on the data format in the Kafka
val decoded = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

You can use the same APIs for working with both streaming & batch data.